# Coding used to call custom list column (Javascript, CAML, Jscript)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am looking for a solution to get past the search query option through SharePoint Online.

We have a department that uses a subsite template to put in new orders.  Within this template there is a list.  One of the fields we want to call is the "Status" field.

We are working on creating a dashboard that calls these lists within a site collection looking for this specific "Status" field value.

Can anyone get me started on some coding, whether it be Javascript, CAML, etc. to put into a script editor webpart to show the lists that meet specific "Status" values?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try below code shared by Md. Tahmidul Abedin

```
function restCallwithCaml(listName, caml) {
             /// get the site url
             var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
             /// set request data     
             var data = { "query" : {"__metadata": 
             { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }, "ViewXml":caml}};
             /// make an ajax call
             $.ajax({
                url: siteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle
                ('"+ listName +"')/GetItems",
                method: "POST",
                data: data,
                headers: {
                   "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                   'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                   'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                }
                success: function (response) {
                    ///do your code
                },
                error: function (data) {
                  ///do your code
                }
            });
       }
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1181172/SharePoint-REST-API-CAML-Query

Update:

Sample caml for choice field:

```
<Where>   
<Eq>    
<FieldRef Name='yourField'/><Value Type='Choice'>value</Value>    
</Eq>    
</Where>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems close, but it looks like it searches by List title?  I am after a query that looks for all lists on a collection, narrowed down by the "Status" field...